# Simple NNTP client for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nntp

I need to download a particular NNTP group.

I do not need to setup any crons, put group contents in /opt and other stuff.

Just run `<fetch-nntp> <server> <group-name> <output-dir>` and be done with it without putting a lot of garbage in the system.

If that `<fetch-nntp>` would not fetch the same messages on the second run — fine. But I can live without it.

All NNTP clients that I've looked at are trying to be a NNTP server as well.

Is there something simpler that is suitable for my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slrn` newsreader comes with `slrnpull`, which is not *exactly* that simple but still can do what you describe. (It does store everything in a *news spool* directory, but you *do not* have to use `/var/spool/news` -- keeping it in `~/news` is just as good.)

Comment: I used `slrnpull` in the past and I want something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Following the links to similar packages from the [Debian `slrnpull` package page](http://packages.debian.org/stable/slrnpull) also brings up [`suck`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/suck) and [`sinntp`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sinntp).  If you really want to roll your own, there's always [`libnews-nntpclient-perl`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libnews-nntpclient-perl).